How to register a Delphi object instance to the IdwsProgramExecution instance and pass it to my custom Eval function?
I have a TABCObject class on the Delphi side.
Then I create
abcobj:=TABCObject.create; abcobj.a := 1

Now, I need to use the abcobj in a custom Eval function added to the DWSscript.
I have two scripts: One is the main, and the second script has been called in a custom Eval function.
What I want is to

A) When I start to exec the Main script, I assign the abcobj to the IdwsProgramExecution of it, then get the abcobj in the custom Eval function,
B) Then pass the abcobj to the second script, then use abcobj in the second script too.

I have tried to assign the abcobj to a
IScriptObj.ExternalObject := abjobj

and
Exec.Info.ScriptObj := LScriptObj;

But inside the custom Eval function, The IScriptObj of the Info: TProgramInfo always is nil value.
How do I add the abcobj to the Exec, pass it to the custom function, and then pass it to the second script?
I do not need to use the object instance in the script, I want to pass it to the custom eval function.
function ExeDWScript(const abcobj: TAbCObject): Boolean;
var
  exec: IdwsProgramExecution;
  LScriptObj: TScriptObjInstance;
  ProgramExecution: TdwsProgramExecution;
  ProgramInfo: TProgramInfo;
begin
  Result := false;
  exec := FMainProgram.BeginNewExecution;
  ProgramExecution := TdwsProgramExecution(exec);
  LScriptObj := TScriptObjInstance.Create(nil, ProgramExecution);
  LScriptObj.ExternalObject := abcobj;  // add the abcobj to 
  Exec.Info.ScriptObj := LScriptObj;
  try
    try
      Exec.RunProgram(0);
      LRe := exec.Result.ToString;
      if LRe <> '' then
        Result := StrToBool(LRe);
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        LRe := E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message;
    end;
  finally
    Exec.EndProgram;
  end;
end;

In the custom eval function.
procedure dwsUnitFunctionsDoAEval(Info: TProgramInfo);
var
  LAbcobj:TABCObject;
  LScriptObj: IScriptObj;
begin
  LScriptObj := Info.ScriptObj; // This always return a nil
  if LScriptObj <> nil then
  begin
    if LScriptObj.ExternalObject <> nil then begin
      LAbcobj:= LScriptObj.ExternalObject as TABCObject;
      // ... ... ... ... ...
      // Pass the LAbcobj to the second script.
      // ... ... ... ... ...
    end;
  end;
end;

I also tried to use the Info.RegisterExternalObject, or the Data property. No success yet.
